# [cgo]Python C API Error: undefined reference to 'Py_True'

Tags: python, go, gcc, python-c-api, cgo

**Environment:**
Ubuntu20.04,Golang 1.9.2,Python 3.7.10

I am trying to use this package: https://github.com/DataDog/go-python3
The problem happened when 'go get github.com/DataDog/go-python3' was executed.

By the way, I have noticed that there is a similar issure:https://github.com/DataDog/go-python3/issues/41. However the answer does not work for me.

I use 'go get -x' to chech what is happening:

```
mininet@mininet-vm:~/go/src/Dockerfiles$ go get -x github.com/DataDog/go-python3
...
pkg-config --cflags python3
pkg-config --libs python3
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g" "-O2" "-L/opt/py/lib" "-lpython3.7m" /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/cgo -objdir 
...
# github.com/DataDog/go-python3
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/github.com/DataDog/go-python3/_obj/_cgo_main.o:/tmp/go-build/github.com/DataDog/go-python3/_obj/cgo-generated-wrappers:236: undefined reference to `Py_True'
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/github.com/DataDog/go-python3/_obj/_cgo_main.o:/tmp/go-build/github.com/DataDog/go-python3/_obj/cgo-generated-wrappers:233: undefined reference to `Py_None'
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/github.com/DataDog/go-python3/_obj/_cgo_main.o:/tmp/go-build/github.com/DataDog/go-python3/_obj/cgo-generated-wrappers:230: undefined reference to `Py_False'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

see CGOFLAGS, I have add  '-L/opt/py/lib -lpython3.7m' correctly to the end by using pkg-config and setting 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' and 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' varibles.

I don't know what happened, maybe go 1.9 is too old? But It seems like a link problem.

I use VM and docker to retry. And the problem is the same.

Thanks for all your possible help.

Comment: Regardless of the any linking problem, go1.9 hasn’t been supported in 5 years. Upgrade the versions before doing anything.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I know it will be so convinent to upgrade the versions, however In my project I need to use go1.9.2 temporaryly. Looking forward to your further advice.